# Failed to create COM object `Excel.Application': "Access is denied"

Tags: php, excel, iis, com, dcom

I am facing problems in creating com object for excel on my server, my program is ended up with throwing an exception **Failed to create COM object `Excel.Application': "Access is denied"**

In event logs I see following error

"The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
 and APPID 
Unavailable
 to the user IIS APPPOOL\ePortal SID (S-1-5-82-1011135971-235349235-4113034207-2765443716-3287928964) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool."

I have given necessary permission but still this error pops up.

Here is the screenshot of permission.

[image]

Thanks in advance